# Row Level Transactions in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, apache-zookeeper

I'm a newbie in HiveQL. When I'm creating a table, I came to know we need to keep TRUE some of the properties of transactions. Then I have gone through what are those:

```
hive>set hive.support.concurrency = true;
hive>set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
hive>set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
hive>set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
hive>set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
hive>set hive.compactor.worker.threads = a positive number on at least one instance of the Thrift metastore service;
```

What exactly `Concurrency,bucketing,Dynamic.partition.mode = 'nonstrict'`?

I have been trying to learn about those things but I'm getting information along with locking mechanisms and ZooKeeper and in memory concepts.

As I'm completely new to this area I'm unable to get a proper knowledge on this property.

Can any one throw some light on this?

Comment: you should add how you are creating your table and why you think those must be true... Additional to that, you can find all the configs here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties,a do you have any specific questions ?

Comment: Yeah but I want to know the purpose of true or false of all the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Hive documentation

```
hive.support.concurrency
```

> Whether Hive supports concurrency or not. A ZooKeeper instance must be
>   up and running for the default Hive lock manager to support read-write
>   locks.
>
> Set to true to support INSERT ... VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE
>   transactions (Hive 0.14.0 and later). For a complete list of
>   parameters required for turning on Hive transactions

```
 hive.enforce.bucketing
```

> Whether bucketing is enforced. If true, while inserting into the
>   table, bucketing is enforced.

`hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode`

> In strict mode, the user must specify at least one static partition in
>   case the user accidentally overwrites all partitions. In nonstrict
>   mode all partitions are allowed to be dynamic.

```
hive.txn.manager
```

> Set this to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager as part of
>   turning on Hive transactions. The default DummyTxnManager replicates
>   pre-Hive-0.13 behavior and provides no transactions.

```
hive.compactor.initiator.on
```

> Whether to run the initiator and cleaner threads on this metastore
>   instance. Set this to true on one instance of the Thrift metastore
>   service as part of turning on Hive transactions. For a complete list
>   of parameters required for turning on transactions, see
>   hive.txn.manager.
>
> It's critical that this is enabled on exactly one metastore service
>   instance (not enforced yet).

`hive.compactor.worker.threads`

> How many compactor worker threads to run on this metastore instance.
>   Set this to a positive number on one or more instances of the Thrift
>   metastore service as part of turning on Hive transactions. For a
>   complete list of parameters required for turning on transactions, see
>   hive.txn.manager.
>
> Worker threads spawn MapReduce jobs to do compactions. They do not do
>   the compactions themselves. Increasing the number of worker threads
>   will decrease the time it takes tables or partitions to be compacted
>   once they are determined to need compaction. It will also increase the
>   background load on the Hadoop cluster as more MapReduce jobs will be
>   running in the background.